# Bismark report before and after Cytosine Methylation Extraction

Tags: methylation

Looking at the sample [report](https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/bismark/PE_report.html) from [Bismark webpage](https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/bismark/), there are two sections: *Cytosine Methylation* and *Cytosine Methylation after Extraction*. However even after reading [User Guide](https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/bismark/Bismark_User_Guide.pdf), I still cannot understand the difference between these two sections.

As far as I understand this, *Cytosine Methylation* section shows summary statistics about Cytosine Methylation in sequenced data and *Cytosine Methylation after Exctraction* shows summary statistics after a Methylation calling, but is not the Methylation calling already part of the first section?

My question therefore is: What is the difference between these two sections of Bismark report?

Comment: Did you try contacting the authors of Bismark? It doesn't seem to be highly used, so I doubt we have here someone who could answer you. (If you find the answer, then post it here for others please)

Comment: I was also looking for an answer to the same question and found this issue. have a look at this post https://github.com/FelixKrueger/Bismark/issues/245